# Rails Bootstrap .span not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Rails and I am using bootstrap-sass gem. My layout looks like this:

```
<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

The problem is that each of the two columns, .span3 and .span 9 are shown full width and one beneath the other. This is the same for any .span combination.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle so we can try out your code, you'll get help more easily. Also, you should mention your bootstrap version you're using (I assume 2.x, but you never know...)

Comment: You might be using bootstrap 2 syntax with bootstrap 3. `span9` changed to `col-md-9` (its not exactly like that, see getbootstrap.com for details on how the new grid works).

Comment: bootstrap-sass: 3.0.0.0.rc2

Comment: Yes, I was using old syntax. Thak you!

Comment: @ThomasKlemm ideally you should turn that into an answer that the poster can mark correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using bootstrap 2 syntax with bootstrap 3. span9 changed to col-md-9 (its not exactly like that, see [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) for details on how the new grid works).

Answer (score 1):

Which version of bootstrap are you using? If it's bootstrap version 3 it's switched to col-md-xx. So you probably need to use col-md-3 & col-md-9.